# Characteristic of a Ring definition

Tags: abstract-algebra

I read the definiton of characteristic of a ring and it doesn't make sense to me 1+1 ...+1(n times) =0 ,we sum the integer 1 n times and we want it to be 0 or there is a different idea I can't get it .

Comment: You do understand that the $1$ you are talking about is the identity of the ring, and not necessarily the $1\in \Bbb Z$, right? It kind of sounds like you expect the identity of every ring will behave like $1\in \Bbb Z$ under addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ring $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, sometimes called $\mathbb{Z}_2$, the only elements are $0,1$, and $1+1=0$.  Hence it is of characteristic $2$.

Comment: You mean we search for the smallest number of times we sum element and divide it by mod 2 so the result is equal to element of the group?

Comment: @Sadams It is not necessary to "do" anything if you understand the notation and operations of the ring: $1$ is an element of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z=R$, $R$ is closed under addition, therefore $1+1$ is in $R$,  and finally  $1+1\equiv 0$ in $R$.

Comment: so in $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ the elements are 0,1,2 and 2+1 =0 right? so the characteristic is 2

Comment: @Sadams in $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$ it is $3$ because $\underbrace{1+1+1}_3=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $G$ be a group and $g\in G$ an arbitrary element. Then there exists one and only one group homomorphism $\phi\colon \Bbb Z\to G$ with the property $\phi(1)=g$. In particular, for a (unitary) ring $R$, there exists a unique group homomorphism from $\Bbb Z$ to the *additive* group of $R$ that maps $1$ to the *multiplicative* neutral of $R$. The kernel of this homomorphism is of the form $n\Bbb Z$ for some non-negative integer $n$ (because all subgroups of $\Bbb Z$ ar of this form). Then we call $n$ the characteristic of $R$. The characteristic is $0$ if and only if our homomorphism is injective.

Clearly, $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ itself has characteristic $n$.